# Faster way to subset a dataframe using pandas

Tags: pandas

The full dataframe is 2.4GB. 
Currently I am creating a boolean mask based on index and selecting a subset of dataframe.
 The index is a DateTimeIndex.
It takes approx 10 min to get the subset dataframe . Is there a faster way to do this?
Please see the code below for your reference.

```
        train_data = pd.read_pickle(self.pkl_path + '/' + "train_data.pkl")
        new_train_data = train_data[(train_data.index.date <= self.end_train.date())
                                    & (self.start_train.date() <= train_data.index.date)]
```

Comment: I would declare dtypes in your `pd.read` this will dramatically speed up the import. Have a nose at the following blog post https://realpython.com/python-pandas-tricks/

Comment: @Datanovice, thnx for the comment. The default way of loading is fast enough and i am happy with it. The main concern is, when it goes to the subsetting part. i have crosschecked the above claim by putting a breakpoint before subset line and after subset line.

Comment: can the data not come from a pickled object? because if this were a csv, this would be easier using the kwarg `chunksize` to subset only a part of the data set, transform it, then at the end concatenate everything. Or use `dask` for parallel processing (same concept, different execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create some data first:

```py
import random, string
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today=datetime.now()
idx=pd.date_range(today, today + timedelta(4999), freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame([{
    'name1': ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10)]),
    'name2': ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(10)]),
    'val1': random.randint(0, 2**16),
    'val2': random.randint(0, 2**16),
    'val3': random.randint(0, 2**16),
    } for j in range(5000)],
    index=idx
)
```

and now check for execution times using `df.index` and a comparison to a date string:

```py
%timeit df[(df.index>='2019-06-01')&('2019-08-01'>=df.index)]
```

> 742 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

versus a comparison between explicit `datetime.date` objects (i.e. using `df.index.date`, the compared dates are the same as above):

```py
%timeit df[(df.index.date>=(today + timedelta(days=25)).date())&((today + timedelta(days=25)).date()>=df.index.date)]
```

> 4.2 ms ± 82.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

It appears you are using the latter, while the former is more performant.

**Update:**

If you want to be a bit faster, you could be more explicit, i.e. relay to a comparison of `numpy.datetime64` arrays by using:

```py
start_date=pd.to_datetime(['2019-06-01 00:00:00']).values[0]
end_date=pd.to_datetime(['2019-08-01 00:00:00']).values[0]

%timeit df[(df.index.values>=start_date)&(df.index.values<=end_date)]
```

> 594 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)